# RDLC Visual Studio - how to make an operation between columns of a columns group?

Tags: dataset, report, rdlc

in the empty column on the screenshot, i'm trying to show the evolution of the "C.A TTC" column between last year and this year, any idea on what expression i can use?

thanks a lot.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ti3gP.png)

i tried a lot of expressions but it's the first time i use a columns group

i tried this with no succes : `= Fields!PV_TTC.Value - Lookup(Fields!ANNEE.Value - 1, Fields!ANNEE.Value, Fields!PV_TTC.Value, "DataSet1")`